# When closing a button, it reopens with slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I commented, I'm putting together 3 rows with two divs each, which contain buttons that show information when you click on them.

What I want is for them to have an effect like "slideDown", so that when you press a button, your information is displayed and when you press it again, it is hidden. On the other hand, I would like that when one is open, and another button is clicked, the information that was visible from the active button is hidden and the information of the other that was activated is displayed.

**The problem is that if I open and close the same button, it opens again. How do I solve it?**

**HTML: (I add only two buttons to not make the code so long)**

```
                <row class="col-xs-12" id="row1">

                    <?php

                        $item = null;
                        $valor = null;

                        $categorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

                        foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {

                            if ($value["categoria"] == "CLÁSICO") {

                            echo '<div class="col-xs-6 btnCategoriasMobile" id="btnClasico">

                                    <button class="btn btn-default backColor btn-block btnCategoriasMobile">
                                        <a class="pixelCategorias">'.$value["categoria"].'</a>

                                    </button>

                                    <div class="infoSubCategorias" id="subcatClasico"';

                                    $item = "id_categoria";

                                    $valor = $value["id"];

                                    $subcategorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item, $valor);

                                    foreach ($subcategorias as $key => $value) {

                                            echo '<li><center><a href="'.$url.$value["ruta"].'" class="pixelSubCategorias">'.$value["subcategoria"].'</a></center></li>';
                                        }   

                                    echo '</div>
                                    </div>';

                            } else if ($value["categoria"] == "LIGHT") {

                            echo '<div class="col-xs-6 btnCategoriasMobile" id="btnLight">

                                    <button class="btn btn-default backColor btn-block btnCategoriasMobile">
                                        <a class="pixelCategorias">'.$value["categoria"].'</a>

                                    </button>

                                    <div class="infoSubCategorias" id="subcatLight"';

                                    $item = "id_categoria";

                                    $valor = $value["id"];

                                    $subcategorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item, $valor);

                                    foreach ($subcategorias as $key => $value) {

                                            echo '<li><center><a href="'.$url.$value["ruta"].'" class="pixelSubCategorias">'.$value["subcategoria"].'</a></center></li>';
                                        }   

                                    echo '</div>
                                    </div>';

                            }

                        }

                    ?>

                </row>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#btnClasico").click(function(){
    $('.infoSubCategorias').slideUp();
    $("#subcatClasico").slideToggle();
 });

$("#btnLight").click(function(){
    $('.infoSubCategorias').slideUp();
    $("#subcatLight").slideToggle();
 });

$("#btnSodio").click(function(){
    $('.infoSubCategorias').slideUp();
    $("#subcatSodio").slideToggle();
 });

$("#btnFibras").click(function(){
    $('.infoSubCategorias').slideUp();
    $("#subcatFibras").slideToggle();
 });

$("#btnVeggie").click(function(){
    $('.infoSubCategorias').slideUp();
    $("#subcatVeggie").slideToggle();
 });

$("#btnCombos").click(function(){
    $('.infoSubCategorias').slideUp();
    $("#subcatCombos").slideToggle();
 });
```

Comment: show your HTML please

Comment: @vishuminhas ok, now I add it :)

Comment: @vishuminhas added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude the target element using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method from set of matched `$('.infoSubCategorias')` before sliding them up.

```
$("#btnCombos").click(function(){
    var target = $("#subcatCombos")
    $('.infoSubCategorias').not(target).slideUp(); 
    target.slideToggle();
 });
```